# Python / How to get logger with absolute path?

Tags: python, logging

I try to use the logging of python:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logInstall = logging.getLogger('/var/log/install.log')

log.info("Everything works great")
logInstall.info("Why is not printed to the log file?")
```

In the log file of the log, every thing works and it prints: "Everything works great"

But in `/var/log/install.log`, I don't see anything.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you seen that the argument to `logging.getLogger()` was a file path ??? It's only a name for your logger object:

> logging.getLogger([name])
>
> Return a logger with the specified name or, if no name is specified, 
>    return a logger which is the root logger of the hierarchy.
>    If specified, the name is typically a dot-separated hierarchical name
>    like “a”, “a.b” or “a.b.c.d”. Choice of these names is entirely up to
>    the developer who is using logging.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger

Where / how this logger logs to (file, stderr, syslog, mail, network call, whatever) depends on how you configure the logging for your own app - the point here is that you decouple the logger's use (in the libs) from the logger config (in the app).

Note that the usual practice is to use `__name__` so you get a logger hierarchy that mimics the packages / modules hierarchy.